# How to create a JSONarray of arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create the following `JSONarray` in Java for asserting in a unit test -

```
[["itemPrice"],["deliveryCharge"]]
```

I tried few things like one below -

```
final JSONArray expectResult = new JSONArray("{[\"itemPrice\"],[\"itemPrice\"]}");
```

I get an error -

```
org.json.JSONException: Names must be strings, but ["itemPrice"] is of type org.json.JSONArray at character 15 of {["itemPrice"],["deliveryCharge"]}
```

And if I tried something like -

```
final JSONArray expectResult = new JSONArray("[[\"itemPrice\"],[\"deliveryCharge\"]]");
```

I get an error -

```
Expected: [<[["itemPrice"],["deliveryCharge"]]>] in any order
     but: was a net.minidev.json.JSONArray (<[["itemPrice"],["deliveryCharge"]]>)
```

I basically need to assert the returned array so trying to form one but unable to do so.

Comment: What's the assertion?

Comment: It's kinda complex but it's like `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.error.errors[*].params",Matchers.arrayContainingInAnyOrder(expectResult));`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
    JSONArray firstArray = new JSONArray();
    firstArray.add("itemPrice");
    JSONArray secondArray = new JSONArray();
    secondArray.add("deliveryCharge");

    JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray();
    parentArray.add(firstArray);
    parentArray.add(secondArray);
```

Print output of it aligns with what you were asking for, I'm just not sure whether it aligns with your approach.